Claims did not set after changing wcf from http to https
Recently, we changed wcf service from http to https. After this, we are unable to set claims. It is set in that method, once we come out of the method, we lose it.
Below is the code to set claims. It works fine with http but fails with https.
var claimsIdentity = new List<ClaimsIdentity>
{
    new ClaimsIdentity(
        new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(Name, securityToken.LoginName),
            new Claim(TenantId, securityToken.TenantID)
        })
};
//set context and thread principal
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

If I add < serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="None" /> in serviceBehavior in wcf configuration file, it again works. Is there any security concern with this?

After changing wcf service from http to https, you need to introduce an SSL certificate. This document describes the relevant content for your reference.
